# Model date rule invalid on save

Tags: cakephp

I got an issue trying to save data in my database using a not Add method, my save code is the following:

```
$this->loadModel('PlanRequest');
$planRe = array(
    'PlanRequest'=>array(
            'booking'=>$book, 
            'user_id'=>$user['id'], 
            'plan_id'=>$plid, 
            'request_date'=>$date->format('d/m/Y h:i:s A'), 
            'number_of_rooms'=>$troom, 
            'number_of_rooms_child'=>$troom2
    ));
$this->PlanRequest->create();
$this->PlanRequest->save($planRe);
```

I'm pretty sure this is the right way to do it, but it is not working, I do not receive any error message also, am I missing something important?

**EDIT**

```
pr($this->PlanRequest->validationErrors)
```

Thanks Nunser! i got the following error from my model:

```
Array
(
    [request_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => Insert a valid date
        )

)
```

In the model the validation is quite simple

```
'request_date'=>array(
            'rule'=>'date',
            'required'=>true,
            'message'=>'Insert a valid date'
        )
```

Comment: if you do `pr($this->PlanRequest->validationErrors)` after the save, do you get anything?

Comment: eddited with the error, now I dont know how to fix this new problem

Comment: I think the date format should be Y-m-d H:i:s

Comment: @MiheretabAlemu same problem, in the database is store as "2/25/2014 12:00:00 AM", after realizing that I got it wrong too i change it to m/d/Y h:i:s, the error still persist

Comment: The date rule in the model format accepts only Y-m-d H:i:s or you need to change the format in the model

Comment: @MiheretabAlemu I "solved it" by setting 'rule'=>'notEmpty' and the date format you proposed, am still concerned about the 'rule'=>'date' not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your rule is simple, it's the one that's causing problems. This is your rule

```
'request_date'=>array(
        'rule'=>'date',
        'required'=>true,
        'message'=>'Insert a valid date'
    )
```

You're not passing any format parameters, so according to [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3adate), the default date format is 'ymd'

> If no keys are supplied, the default key that will be used is ‘ymd’: e.g. 2006-12-27 or 06-12-27 (separators can be a space, period, dash, forward slash)

So, you need to modify this

```
 'request_date'=>$date->format('d/m/Y h:i:s A'),
```

to adjust to the default date rule, or change the rule to adjust to your values (with second and/or third parameter of the rule). Example:

```
'request_date'=>array(
        'rule'=> array('date', 'my'),
        'required'=>true,
        'message'=>'Insert a valid date'
    )
```

(that accepts the dates 06/12 for example). I don't know if you *need* this format 'd/m/Y h:i:s A' or you're ok with another one, so you have to see if it's the rule you need to change or the parameters.